# Restrict document fields addition in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Does MongoDB provide any mechanism to restrict addition of a new field to a document in a collection?

I would think that the best way to do that would be using some kind of "add new field" privilege, but it seems that MongoDB has got just two roles - readonly and normal. Is there any other way to "lock" a collection?

Comment: What are you trying to prevent? It's a schema-less system, so it doesn't have logic for prevention/restriction of the documents stored in a collection at the database layer. It's expected to be handled by a driver/business logic layer.

Comment: It says it's a [flexible schema](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/) system and not schema-less. I would like to know if it's possible to prevent new fields to be added or removed from a document in a collection, but I guess it's not

Comment: OK -- sure, it's a flexible schema & [schema-less](http://www.mongodb.org/about/introduction/) (they're [flexible](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/119945109/why-schemaless) in their terminology over the years). :) There's no way to prevent at the database layer new fields being added or removed.

Comment: You can add users to Mongo that have different access levels at the database level. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security/  I believe you can make a given user account read-only.